# I have an Python project, and when I update and submit the code and try to rebuild the project, the code is not change

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

    db:
      container_name: postgres
      image: postgres
      hostname: db
      environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password123
      # ports:
      #   - "5432:5432"
      #   (HOST:CONTAINER)
      volumes:
        - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

    redis:
      image: redis
      container_name: redis
      hostname: redis
      restart: always
      # ports:
      #   - "6379:6379"
      # extra_hosts:
      #   - "redis:0.0.0.0"
      volumes:
        - redisdata:/data

    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        build: 
          context: ./
          dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        ports:
        - "8080:80"
        volumes:
        - api_data:/docker_api
        - ./log:/var/log/nginx
        depends_on:
        - backend

    backend:
        container_name: backend
        build: ./backend
        restart: always
        command: uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
        volumes:
        - api_data:/docker_api
        links:
          - db
          - redis
        depends_on:
        - db
        - redis

volumes:
    api_data:
    pgdata:
    redisdata:
```

backend/dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest
LABEL maintainer ugodubai
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /docker_api
WORKDIR /docker_api
COPY . /docker_api
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install vim
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream uwsgi{
    server unix:/docker_api/app.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost ugodubai.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /media  {
      alias /docker_api/backend/media;
    }

    location /api {
      include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass uwsgi;
    } 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
        index index.html;
    }

    index index.html;

    location @router {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
    }
}
```

My project uses Docker Compose to deploy a Django app, I am having a problem when I update my code and submit it to GitHub, then I `git pull` on the server and use `docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose Up -d --force-recreate`, the code in the container has not changed.

My current idea is to change the code in the container and keep the images in docker_api/backend/media not cleared. How can I do this? 
docker_api/backend/media saves user-uploaded images.

I guess this problem may come from the data volume, api_data: /docker_api will use the entire application as a data volume, so every time the rebuild code is overwritten by the data volume? But I need nginx to use the docker_api/app.sock data as a reverse proxy.

The problem is solved, 
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    hostname: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password123
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    # networks:
    #   - database_network

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./frontend/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - static_volume:/backend/static
      - media_volume:/backend/media  
    depends_on:
      - backend
    # networks:
    #   - nginx_network

  backend:
      container_name: backend
      build: ./backend
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - .:backend
        - static_volume:/backend/static
        - media_volume:/backend/media
      links:
        - db
        - redis
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
      # networks:
      #   - nginx_network
      #   - database_network

# networks:
#   nginx_network:
#     driver: bridge
#   database_network:
#     driver: bridge

volumes:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream backend_server{
    # server unix:/docker_api/app.sock;
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost ugodubai.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /media  {
      alias /backend/media;
    }

    location /api {
      # uwsgi_pass uwsgi;
      proxy_pass http://backend_server;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_redirect off;
    } 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
        index index.html;
    }

    index index.html;

    location @router {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Dockerfile does not include an `ENTRYPOINT` nor `CMD` instruction which describes the process that will be started when the container is run. I would expect to see something similar to `ENTRYPOINT python your-solution.py`.

Comment: Please add the `docker-compose.yaml` (or equivalent).

Comment: see git@github.com:marscj/ugo.git   .thanks bro

Comment: Please edit into this question the code that you want readers to see. We find that external links containing code break frequently, which means that future readers lose the opportunity to learn from the question (and its answers).

Comment: IIUC the solution would be to separate the code from the data. You're currently creating `backend` by putting the code in `/docker_api` but you then overwrite this directory (and your code) with whatever's in the `api_data` volume in the Docker Compose file `volumes: - api_data:/docker_api`.

Comment: @ DazWilkin tanks，bro